# SQL check if a value exists in a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query returns all releaseID that have only the territoryid =200

```
select rt.ReleaseId from ReleaseTerritory rt 
group by rt.ReleaseId
having SUM(case when rt.TerritoryId=200 then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

How can i do to check if the value **47033** exists or not in the resuls of the query above.
Many thanks.

Comment: Could you confirm what sort of tools you are looking to use - do you want it as part of the query, in c#, excel, being able to use ctrl+f?

Comment: Why group by ??...why not simply _IF Exists(select rt.ReleaseId from ReleaseTerritory rt where rt.TerritoryId=200 and rt.ReleaseId=47033)_

Comment: @Pranav it would not be the same logic, the script is currently checking for other rows where TerritoryId<>200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a where clause that limits the results returned to specific `ReleaseId`.

```
select rt.ReleaseId from ReleaseTerritory rt
where rt.ReleaseId = 47033 
group by rt.ReleaseId
having SUM(case when rt.TerritoryId=200 then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

To receive a value such as `yes or exists` (Warning Untested Code):

```
select case when count(rt.ReleaseId) = 0 
then 'Doesnt Exist' 
else 'Exists' end as exists 
from ReleaseTerritory rt
where rt.ReleaseId = 47033 
group by rt.ReleaseId
having SUM(case when rt.TerritoryId=200 then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

Comment: ok this works fine :) , do you know how to use the if statement to have like a yes prompt if rt.ReleaseId = 47033  exists ?

Comment: since count(rt.ReleaseID) will never be 0, this added check seems unnesassary. Also Note that exists is a reserved word

Comment: I am not sure but I think you forgot a if in the query

Comment: @saadamiens there is no IF in 2008 queries

Comment: @saadamiens Can you explain further?

Comment: Ok , I get an error message like Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exists'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ReleaseId from ReleaseTerritory
where ReleaseId = 47033
and TerritoryId=200
except
select ReleaseId from ReleaseTerritory 
where ReleaseId = 47033
and TerritoryId <> 200
```